# Create data objects from Xaml file

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

Currently I am trying to load some Xaml files to create testdata.

I used the Xaml files to create data for the WPF designer in Visual Studio ([DesignData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee823176.aspx)).
Now I want to reuse them in my Unit Tests. I need to load them somehow programmatically. Here is a small test program:

```
// The data model
class TestItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

The Xaml data file:

```
<sys:ArrayList xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
               xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
  <local:TestItem Name="Item1" Value="123" Category="Cat1" />
  <local:TestItem Name="Item2" Value="456" Category="Cat1" />
  <local:TestItem Name="Item3" Value="789" Category="Cat2" />
</sys:ArrayList>
```

And now I try to read the data:

```
var reader = new System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader();

var obj = reader.LoadAsync(File.OpenRead("Test.xaml"));
```

The LoadAsync method throws an XamlParseException.

> 'Cannot create unknown type
>   '{clr-namespace:WpfApplication1}TestItem'

Do I need to register my TestItem class somehow? Is this the right approach to solve my problem, or am I missusing [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) here? I also spent some time in the [System.Xaml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xaml.aspx)-Namespace. But I couldn't get it working.

Edit:

In the sample code above I have set the Build Action to None. When I set it to DesignData the file cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error. Making the TestItem class public solved my problem.

```
// The data model
public class TestItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your approach should work fine.

You mention that you're reusing the same code to write unit tests (which is where you get the exception, if I understand it correctly). If you're writing tests and loading the XAML in other assembly than the one where `TestItem` is defined, then you'll need to specify the assembly name in the `xmlns:local` attribute.

Comment: I created the above sample code in one assembly. The xmlns:local is set to the correct namespace. I have set the build action of the Xaml file to None (see my update). Still doesnt work.